# How to convert Mapinfo “.Map” file (without .TAB) into SHP?

Tags: shapefile, mapinfo, tab

I've got several MapInfo files but i don't have the .TAB.

I only have:

- M044.DAT
- M044.ID
- M044.IND
- M044.MAP

I need to convert these files to SHP.

I tried to read those files with MapInfo Proviewer 11 and QGIS 2.2 with no success...

Regards,

Comment: A tab file is just text you can hand craft it if you know what is inside the files

Comment: do you have any similarly formatted data, which you could copy and rename the tab file to create a complete set of files that can be read into MapInfo (or for conversion using ogr2ogr)?

Comment: i don't know excatly what's inside the other files...

Comment: You can open the .DAT file in Excel and get the column names and probably guess the type.

From there as @NathanW said manually construct the TAB, then convert.